# Sum duplicates then remove all but first occurrence

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame (~5000 rows, 6 columns) that contains some duplicate values for an `id` variable. I have another continuous variable `x`, whose values I would like to sum for each duplicate `id`. The observations are time dependent, there are `year` and `month` variables, and I'd like to keep the chronologically first observation of each duplicate `id` and add the subsequent dupes to this first observation.

I've included dummy data that resembles what I have: `dat1`. I've also included a data set that shows the structure of my desired outcome: `outcome`.

I've tried two strategies, neither of which quite give me what I want (see below). The first strategy gives me the correct values for `x`, but I loose my year and month columns - I need to retain these for all the first duplicate `id` values. The second strategy doesn't sum the values of `x` correctly.

Any suggestions for how to get my desired outcome would be much appreciated.

```
# dummy data set
set.seed(179)
dat1 <- data.frame(id = c(1234, 1321, 4321, 7423, 4321, 8503, 2961, 1234, 8564, 1234),
                   year = rep(c("2006", "2007"), each = 5),
                   month = rep(c("December", "January"), each = 5),
                   x = round(rnorm(10, 10, 3), 2))

# desired outcome
outcome <- data.frame(id = c(1234, 1321, 4321, 7423, 8503, 2961, 8564),
                      year = c(rep("2006", 4), rep("2007", 3)),
                      month = c(rep("December", 4), rep("January", 3)),
                      x = c(36.42, 11.55, 17.31, 5.97, 12.48, 10.22, 11.41))

# strategy 1:
library(plyr)
dat2 <- ddply(dat1, .(id), summarise, x = sum(x))

# strategy 2:
# partition into two data frames - one with unique cases, one with dupes
dat1_unique <- dat1[!duplicated(dat1$id), ]
dat1_dupes <- dat1[duplicated(dat1$id), ]

# merge these data frames while summing the x variable for duplicated ids
# with plyr
dat3 <- ddply(merge(dat1_unique, dat1_dupes, all.x = TRUE),
              .(id), summarise, x = sum(x))
# in base R
dat4 <- aggregate(x ~ id, data = merge(dat1_unique, dat1_dupes,
                  all.x = TRUE), FUN = sum)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got different sums, but it were b/c I forgot the seed:

```
> dat1$x <- ave(dat1$x, dat1$id, FUN=sum)
> dat1[!duplicated(dat1$id), ]
    id year    month     x
1 1234 2006 December 25.18
2 1321 2006 December 15.06
3 4321 2006 December 15.50
4 7423 2006 December  7.16
6 8503 2007  January 13.23
7 2961 2007  January  7.38
9 8564 2007  January  7.21
```

(To be safer It would be better to work on a copy. And you might need to add an ordering step.)

Comment: wow, that's great! I didn't fudge the math - I think you maybe didn't copy the seed number I put at the top of the code. I get the values I gave in my `outcome` dataset using your code when I use that seed. Thanks so much for such a neat two liner!

Comment: Ooops. sorry. I probably did miss the random seed being set since it was such a small data.frame.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with `data.table` (quicker, more memory efficiently than plyr)

With a  bit of self-joining fun using `mult` ='first'. Keying by id year and month will sort by id, year then month.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat1, key = c('id','year','month'))


# setnames is required as there are two x columns that get renamed x, x.1
DT1 <- setnames(DT[DT[,list(x=sum(x)),by=id],mult='first'][,x:=NULL],'x.1','x')
```

---

Or a simpler approach :

```
DT = as.data.table(dat1)

DT[,x:=sum(x),by=id][!duplicated(id)]

     id year    month     x
1: 1234 2006 December 36.42
2: 1321 2006 December 11.55
3: 4321 2006 December 17.31
4: 7423 2006 December  5.97
5: 8503 2007  January 12.48
6: 2961 2007  January 10.22
7: 8564 2007  January 11.41
```

Comment: thanks so much for your solutions! The above `data.table` solution works perfectly, but the syntax looks horrendous (for me - being unfamiliar with `data.table`). I noticed you had a `plyr` solution in your original answer before editing. Your `plyr` code gave the following error: `Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE`. If you have time, would you mind providing a `plyr` example that works? I feel the syntax may be more understandable to me and the `data.table` performance gains are insignificant for 5k rows of data (I don't need to scale this in future).

Comment: @Chris, My `plyr`  solution was not correct (which is why I had deleted it). If you can ensure that the data are sorted (correctly) by year then month. then `ddply(dat1, .(id), summarise, x = sum(x),month = month[1],year = year[1])` would work.